# Import data from csv with timestamps

Tags: r, csv, timestamp

My csv file looks like this:

```
A,A,B,B,C,C,… 
Timestamp,Price,Timestamp,Price,Timestamp,Price,…
6/1/15,20,6/1/15,97,6/1/15,279,… 
5/29/15,21,5/29/15,96,5/29/15,276,…
```

Where A-C are stocks with daily prices. I would like to convert it in this form,

```
            A   B   C
6/01/2015   20  97  279
5/29/2015   21  96  276
m/d/Y     price price price
```

Firts I tried with `readSeries(file="name.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";", format="%d/%m/%Y")` however than I get the date as well as the price in separate columns for each stock. Which looks like this

```
               A    A          B    B          C    C
[1,]    06/01/2015  20  06/01/2015  97  06/01/2015  279
[2,]    5/29/2015   21  5/29/2015   96  5/29/2015   276
```

My second attempt was to read it with `read.zoo(file="name.csv", sep=",", header=TRUE, index="Timestamp", format="%m/%d/%Y")`. Here I get the error message `index has 6375 bad entries at data rows`, but the format is correct.
My question is which of the two applied functions is more suitable for my problem and how could I achieve my desired output?

Comment: Maybe you need a two-step solution. First read in your data, then transform it to th eformat you want it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will suffice?

```
stocks="A,A,B,B,C,C
6/1/15,20,6/1/15,97,6/1/15,279
5/29/15,21,5/29/15,96,5/29/15,276
"
df = read.csv(text=stocks)
s = seq (2, ncol(df), by = 2)
idx = c(1, s)  # only want 1st column and stock price columns
df2 = df[,idx]
colnames(df2) = c("date", colnames(df)[s-1])
```

Output `df2`

```
     date  A  B   C
1  6/1/15 20 97 279
2 5/29/15 21 96 276
```

#### UPDATE:

Based upon a comment discussion I replaced the `colnames(df2)...` line with the code below in order to put the dates in the right format and place them in the rownames of the dataframe. Unfortunately, rownames of a dataframe can only be a character vector and not in a date format. (Side note: be careful using rownames in a dataframe: `http://www.perfectlyrandom.org/2015/06/16/never-trust-the-row-names-of-a-dataframe-in-R/`)

```
rownames(df2) = strftime(as.Date(df2[,1], "%m/%d/%y"), format = "%m/%d/%Y")
df2[,1]=NULL
colnames(df2) = c(colnames(df)[s-1])
```

Output `df2`

```
            A  B   C
06/01/2015 20 97 279
05/29/2015 21 96 276
```

Comment: This is it. Because each date is in a separate row this solution gives the desired output and the code is very short. Thank you very much!

Comment: I was a little too fast with celebrating. Maybe I was not precise enough in the first question. But my desired output is a time series. Therefore the first column should not be the "date" but rather the Stock A. and the column "date" should be recognized as date. I tried to do it with `as.Date(df2$date, "%m/%d/%Y")` and `read.zoo` but either I get 06.01.0015 as date or the second function gives error. My last hope were `as.ts` and `as.timeSeries` but also no results here.

Comment: Don't use `%Y` for 2 digits dates; use `%y`. `as.Date` output needs to be converted to the format that you want with `strftime`. Example: `t = "6/1/15"; t2 = as.Date(t, "%m/%d/%y"); strftime(t2, "%m/%d/%y"); --> "06/01/15"`

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Here we use `read.zoo`.  We have used `textConnection(Lines)` and `text=Lines` to keep this self contained but in reality replace each of those with `file = "name.csv"` .

First we count the fields giving `n`.  Then we read in the data and we specify a header, comma-separated fields and the date format. (Note that given the data shown at the top of the question the format should specify the year as `%y` and not as the `%Y` shown in the question.) The second line of the input begins with a T so specify that T starts a comment to effectively skip that line.  Next we specify `check.names=FALSE` to prevent it from mangling column names.  Finally, assume that the dates on each row are the same so that we only need the first date on each row.  Using `colClasses` we can omit the other date columns by specifying that they are of class `NULL`.

```
library(zoo)

Lines <- "A,A,B,B,C,C
Timestamp,Price,Timestamp,Price,Timestamp,Price
6/1/15,20,6/1/15,97,6/1/15,279
5/29/15,21,5/29/15,96,5/29/15,276"

n <- count.fields(textConnection(Lines), sep = ",")[1]
colClasses <- c("character", "numeric", rep(c("NULL", "numeric"), n/2-1))

read.zoo(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = ",", format = "%m/%d/%y",
 comment = "T",  check.names = FALSE, colClasses = colClasses)
```

This gives:

```
            A  B   C
2015-05-29 21 96 276
2015-06-01 20 97 279
```

If it's OK to hard code the number of fields we could reduce the code slghtly by omitting the `count.fields` statement and replacing `n/2-1` with `2`.

**1a)** If there can be a T in the header row then use this instead:

```
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))[-2]
read.zoo(text = L, header = TRUE, sep = ",", format = "%m/%d/%y", 
  check.names = FALSE, colClasses = colClasses)
```

**2)** An alternative in base R using `colClasses` computed above is:

```
DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, comment = "T", check.names = FALSE, colClasses = colClasses)
DF[[1]] <- as.Date(DF[[1]], "%m/%d/%y")
names(DF)[1] <- "Date"
```

**2a)** Similarly, if the first line can contain a T then use this instead where `L` is from (1a) and `colClasses` is from (1).

```
DF <- read.csv(text = L, check.names = FALSE, colClasses = colClasses)
DF[[1]] <- as.Date(DF[[1]], "%m/%d/%y")
names(DF)[1] <- "Date"
```

Comment: Thank you too for your proposal. However, I would rather not add any lines to the actual file. I also tried your solution and it gave some errors (probably I did some small mistakes). Nevertheless thank you for your effort, I appreciate it.

Comment: Adding lines to the actual file???    This only reads the data. It does not add anything.   The code works with the supplied data in the question and the output is shown.